# Show first value in array

Tags: laravel

I want to show the first value only in an array where I use the lowest price per sortBy.

To display the array I'm using return array_values and it works normally bringing 3 values, however when using reset it brings me a single value but the return doesn't work.

Code to get only 1 value.

```
$arrays = array_values(
            collect($this->stores)
                ->filter(fn($store) => $store['active'])
                ->map(function($store) {
                    unset($store['margin']);
                    unset($store['refund']);

                    $store['price'] = ceil($store['price']);
                    $store['points'] = $this->hotsite->convertPoints($store['price']);

                    return $store;
                })
                ->sortBy('price')
                ->toArray()
        );

$first_value = reset(arrays);

return $first_value;
```

Code that works normally but displays more than one value.

```
return array_values(
            collect($this->stores)
                ->filter(fn($store) => $store['active'])
                ->map(function($store) {
                    unset($store['margin']);
                    unset($store['refund']);

                    $store['price'] = ceil($store['price']);
                    $store['points'] = $this->hotsite->convertPoints($store['price']);

                    return $store;
                })
                ->sortBy('price')
                ->toArray()
        );
```

Method toArray()

```
public function toArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'short_description' => $this->short_description,
            'details' => $this->details,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'information' => $this->information,
            'about' => $this->about,
            'validation_message' => $this->validation_message,
            'price' => $this->getPrice(),
            'points' => $this->getPoints(),
            'thumbnail' => $this->thumbnail? new ProductImage($this->thumbnail) : null,
            'images' => $this->getImages(),
            'soldOut' => $this->isSoldOut(),
            'stores'  => $this->getStores()
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in the query directly without having to get all the stores then filter them.

Assuming the field `active` is integer 1 or 0, and `stores()` is a relation method.

```
return ceil($this->stores()->where('active', '=', 1)->value('price'));
```

Comment: Using the code given from the undefined method.

Comment: @testCode how are you populating `$this->stores` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you require this to return an array but you can pull the first value out of the collection that you already have using the `first()` method.

```
return   collect($this->stores)
                ->filter(fn($store) => $store['active'])
                ->map(function($store) {
                    unset($store['margin']);
                    unset($store['refund']);

                    $store['price'] = ceil($store['price']);
                    $store['points'] = $this->hotsite->convertPoints($store['price']);

                    return $store;
                })
                ->sortBy('price')
                ->first()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first

Comment: toArray is method,I edited the post inserting the method to array.